# confusion_matrix error 'DataFrame' "object is not callable"

Tags: python, compiler-errors, confusion-matrix

What am I doing wrong? I set both vars to list. Also tried `np.array`.

```
y = list(y_test.values)
yhat = list(predictions)

print(y)
print(yhat)

confusion_matrix = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y, yhat), columns=["Predicted False", "Predicted True"], index=["Actual False", "Actual True"])
display(confusion_matrix)
```

Out:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ..., 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ..., 0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-e1640f0e3b13> in <module>()
     45 print(yhat)
     46 
---> 47 confusion_matrix = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y, yhat), columns=["Predicted False", "Predicted True"], index=["Actual False", "Actual True"])
     48 display(confusion_matrix)
     49 

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Not sure what's going on here...

Comment: You are creating a DataFrame called "confusion_matrix" and then assigning as values the result of a function with the same name: "confusion_matrix(y, yhat)". Maybe you should check that.

Comment: @Ivanovitch, changed the name, still same error

Comment: are you calling a function? if so, please post it.

Comment: @Ivanovitch, just the built in `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix()`

Comment: Possibly `confusion_matrix` was overwritten as a dataframe from your previous run. So now the function `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix()` does not work. try importing the function again or just restart Python and change the name of your confusion matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you doing that in a notebook? If so, maybe the `confusion_matrix` method has been shadowed by the DataFrame when you called it the first time. Try to change the variable name and restart the kernel.

Comment: that's exactly what happened it looks like %\ thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_true = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]
```

When I run `confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)` the result is the following:

```
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Be aware that the result, for this particular input, is a 3x3 matrix, so for this case you will need a list with three names for the columns and index.
You can put the result directly into a Dataframe like so:

```
pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred),columns=['column 1','column 2','column 3'], index=['index 1', 'index 2','index 3'])
```

which give the following result:

```
     column 1  column 2  column 3
index 1         2         0         0
index 2         0         0         1
index 3         1         0         2
```